# Angular + webpack + nodeJS: Return the index.html when asking subfolder

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I've taken [this starting pack](https://github.com/lamecoder/angular2-node-express-webpack) which I found nice. Everything works fine, but if I refresh when being on a component(e.g. on  http://localhost:3000/account-list ) I got 404(since the page doesn't exist.

How should I modify this example to have the index.html page returned?

In fact to have any URL(but the one with a existing file) returing this index.html?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, if a route works once then it should work on refresh as well. Otherwise bookmarking would yet again not be possible

Comment: @Gimby? Not really, angular is managing client side the URL. why you click on the link pointing to `account-list`, there is no page reload, it's angular loading the components. But when I press F5, the server receives a request to serve a folder named `account-list` which doesn't exist server side. If the server returns the `index.html` page, it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution(I think); I found the express part on `main.js` and I replaced the `app.get` for:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (path.extname(req.path).length > 0) {
        // normal static file request
        next();
    }
    else {
        // redirect all html requests to `index.html`
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../dist/index.html'));
    }
});
```